# PrimaryLanguageOverride does not work in release appxbundle

Tags: c#, uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

I am currently working on a UWP project, and I have implemented a language change feature, below is the code snippet which was used to do so

```
Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = App.userLang;
await Task.Delay(100);
Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
```

The feature works fine when debugging, but the feature in the application installed from the side loaded app package does not work. Why is this?
(The feature does not work on a mobile or a PC)

Comment: Was it on the same machine when debugging and side loading your app?

Comment: I fixed the issue with building the app into different architectures (.appx to ARM, x86, x64 seperately).. building it into .appxbundle somehow makes it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

**One possible cause** is the resource for the override language is not installed when during installation.

> By default when you build an app bundle (.appxbundle), only your default resources for language, scale, and DirectX feature level are built into the app package.

You can rename the `.appxbundle` file to `.zip` file to view its contents, an `appxbundle` is essentially a zip file.

Inside the bundle, you can find the app package with the default resource, which looks like

```
YourPackage_1.0.0.1_x64.appx
```

Resource packs for other languages, they are separate .appx, which looks like

```
YourPackage_1.0.0.1_language-fr.appx
YourPackage_1.0.0.1_language-de.appx
```

During the installation, only the app package and the resource required by the device's primary language are installed. So if you later switch to another language, the app cannot load the resource.

If your app is distributed via the Windows Store, the required resource will be downloaded automatically from the Store, but this will not happen since your app is side-loaded.

To verify if it is the cause, just double click the resource pack for the missing language to install it, and restart the app to observe the symptom is gone.

**The solution is to** [Build resources into your app package, instead of into a resource pack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-resources/build-resources-into-app-package).

**Short answer**

Open the project file (.csproj), add the following line to the `PropertyGroup` element.

```
<AppxDefaultResourceQualifiers>Language=en-US;fr-FR;...(add all the languages you need to support)</AppxDefaultResourceQualifiers>
```

Comment: thanks @kennyzx  , you saved my life. I've added the line in the first node `PropertyGroup` and now the change language works.